# Error : Yam is Undefined, while unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I was unit testing an application and I am stuck at one point. I am posting the problem below with code snippet.

This code is used to popup yammer window.

The yam variable is declared outside the component like this

```
declare var yam: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'cs-artifact-related',
  templateUrl: './artifact-related.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./artifact-related.component.css']
})
```

and it is used in the following method

```
public yammerWindowPopup(ownername, prjName): void {
    yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup({
      customButton: true,
      defaultMessage: this.getYammerWindowPopupMessage(ownername, prjName),
      pageUrl: this.copyArtifactUrl.split('?')[0]
    });
  }
```

I have written following code to unit test this

```
it('should call yammerWindowPopup method', () => {
    component.yammerWindowPopup("Owner1", "Test Project");
});
```

and I am getting this error when I run ng test

```
yam is not defined
```

The constraint is I cannot declare yam inside since it is a pre written code.

So I have two questions

1. How to access variable which is defined outside component in spec file?
2. How to resolve the above error?
   Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yam is a third party dependency. Therefore you don't include it in your unit tests.
The best practice for testing components or services that depend on third party modules, is to mock the third party dependency and use the mock in place of actual third party code inside your unit test.

Step 1: Mock yam:

```
const yamMock = {
    platform: {
        yammerShareOpenPopup: () => {} //just an empty function
    }
}
```

Step 2: Use yamMock in place of actual yam - drop it in your unit test configuration for the component:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { 
                provide: yam,
                useValue: yamMock
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

Step3: spy on the mocked yam `yammerShareOpenPopup` function to see if it was called:

```
it('should call yammerWindowPopup method', () => {
    spyOn(yam.platform, 'yammerShareOpenPopup');

    component.yammerWindowPopup("Owner1", "Test Project");

    expect(yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: I was getting the same error even after trying out your solution. However after adding the following file in Karma.conf.js it started working.                                files: [
      { pattern: 'https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js', watched: false },   
    ],